# How to create transparent video from Blender (eg. logo/animation screen) to be played as part of Android/iOS app?

Tags: android, ios, blender, webm, mov

I would like to create an animation in Blender which has a transparent background and play this as a logo/animation screen within an app for Android/iOS phones/devices.

I am wondering if this is possible.

I understand I can export from Blender as a series of transparent PNG images and these can be assembled into a transparent MOV or WEBM video file.

Would either or both be then possible for me to integrate directly into my app and have the Android/iOS device manifest the transparency of the logo/animation when the app running?

Would I have to use WEBM for Android and MOV for iOS?

To be clear I want to be able to see the layers of my application that sit below the animation/icon within my app while it is running.

I have read conflicting things about whether these format videos are naturally supported by devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but the alpha layer of the video will only be usable in video editing software - if you were to play the exported video in an html  element, for instance, the alpha parts would be black because the video player just does that by default. You would only be able to use that alpha channel in video editing software like After Effects, for instance.

I don't think an alpha video would be the way to go for your app usecase, but I'm not familiar with how videos are rendered in whatever environment you are using